# How to efficiently swap elements between columns in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I asked a similar question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959032/how-to-efficiently-swap-elements-in-a-dataframe), but I just realized that the previous example was a little too special in the sense that the factor levels are equally-spaced. Here I want to reframe the question in a more generic way, and the solutions in the old thread would not work properly.

Suppose that we have the following dataframe in `R`:

```
set.seed(1)
(tmp <- data.frame(x = 1:10, R1 = sample(c('A','D','F','G','I'), 10, replace = TRUE), R2 = sample(c('D','F','G','I','Z'), 10, replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))

    x R1 R2
1   1  D  F
2   2  D  D
3   3  F  I
4   4  I  F
5   5  D  I
6   6  I  G
7   7  I  I
8   8  G  Z
9   9  G  F
10 10  A  I
```

Notice that the two columns `R1` and `R2` do not share exactly the same elements. I want to do the following: if the difference between the elemet index (sequential order among the elements) of column `R1` and that of column `R2` is an odd number, the levels of the two factors need to be switched between them, which can be performed through the following code:

```
for(ii in 1:dim(tmp)[1]) {
   kk <- which(levels(as.factor(tmp$R2)) %in% tmp[ii,'R2'], arr.ind = TRUE) - which(levels(as.factor(tmp$R1)) %in% tmp[ii,'R1'], arr.ind = TRUE)
   if(kk%%2!=0) { # swap the elements between the two columns
      qq <- tmp[ii,]$R1
      tmp[ii,]$R1 <- tmp[ii,]$R2
      tmp[ii,]$R2 <- qq
  }
}
```

As the two columns `R1` and `R2` don't share the same elements, I purposefully created the dataframe `tmp` with `R1` and `R2` not as factors so that I could swamp the elements between the two columns with the kludge code above. Below is the output after the swapping:

```
    x R1 R2
1   1  D  F
2   2  D  D
3   3  I  F
4   4  I  F
5   5  D  I
6   6  G  I
7   7  I  I
8   8  Z  G
9   9  F  G
10 10  I  A
```

My solution is too awkward and slow for a big dataframe. Any elegant way to perform this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# convert to character
dat[, c("R1", "R2")] <- lapply(dat[, c("R1", "R2")], as.character)
```

Next, we vectorize your row-change condition. All TRUE elements are those rows to be evaluated and swapped if necessary.

```
# get logical inidcator for elements to change
changeInd <- !!((match(dat$R2, levels(as.factor(dat$R2))) -
                match(dat$R1, levels(as.factor(dat$R1)))) %% 2)

# perform swapping for given rows
dat[changeInd, c("R1", "R2")] <- dat[changeInd, c("R2", "R1")]
```

Here, we use `match` to select the rows where the changes are needed. After this, perform the simple swapping of variables with `[`.

This returns

```
dat
    x R1 R2
1   1  D  F
2   2  D  D
3   3  F  I
4   4  F  I
5   5  D  I
6   6  G  I
7   7  I  I
8   8  G  Z
9   9  F  G
10 10  A  I
```

---

*Note* There may be a typo in the desired output. Since

```
identical((sapply(seq_len(nrow(dat)),
           function(x) which(levels(as.factor(dat$R2)) %in% dat[x,'R2'], arr.ind = TRUE) -
                       which(levels(as.factor(dat$R1)) %in% dat[x,'R1'], arr.ind = TRUE)) %% 2) != 0,
          changeInd)
[1] TRUE
```

### data

```
dat <-
structure(list(x = 1:10, R1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("D", "F", "G", "I", "Z"), class = "factor"), 
    R2 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("A", 
    "D", "F", "G", "I"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("x", 
"R1", "R2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice solution! What are the double exclamation marks `!!` for in `changeInd`?

Comment: `!!` is equivalent to (a shorter, but less readable version) of `as.logical`. The first `!` performs a conversion to the logical negative and the second negates the negation.